# Remove first value within a partition of data in a dataframe, reindex and make a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with the following data columns

```
+------+--------+------------+---+---+---+
| area | locale |    date    | i | t | o |
+------+--------+------------+---+---+---+
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-03-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-04-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-05-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-06-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-07-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def12  | 2001-03-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def12  | 2001-04-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def12  | 2001-05-01 | 1 |   |   |
| def  | def12  | 2001-06-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def12  | 2001-07-01 |   |   | 1 |
+------+--------+------------+---+---+---+
```

Example output:

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+
| area | locale |    date    |  end date  | i | t | o |
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-04-01 | 2001-05-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-06-01 | 2001-07-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-07-01 |            |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-04-01 | 2001-05-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 | 1 |   |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-06-01 | 2001-07-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-07-01 |            |   |   | 1 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+
```

What I have to do is make a set of columns out of a single column.  Now technically date in and of itself is the "start date" so I can just rename it.  That is the easy part.  The part I am having a hard time with is within each area/locale I need to create a "end date." That end date is merely the next date in line within that partition, unless there isn't one and then it would just be None or it could be the same date EG. 2001-07-01.

Is there a way to achieve this within pandas?

I tried

```
df['end_date'] = df.groupby('date').Date.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1).reset_index(0)['locale'])
```

but it doesn't like that.  gives me an error 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: Need to see some expected output for this data.

Comment: okay, can do; one sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` on `area` and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
df['end date'] = df.groupby('area')['date'].shift(-1)

print (df)

    area    locale          date    i    t    o      end date
0   abc     abc25     2001-03-01    1              2001-04-01 
1   abc     abc25     2001-04-01         1         2001-05-01 
2   abc     abc25     2001-05-01    1              2001-06-01 
3   abc     abc25     2001-06-01         1         2001-07-01 
4   abc     abc25     2001-07-01              1           NaN
5   def     def12     2001-03-01         1         2001-04-01 
6   def     def12     2001-04-01         1         2001-05-01 
7   def     def12     2001-05-01    1              2001-06-01 
8   def     def12     2001-06-01              1    2001-07-01 
9   def     def12     2001-07-01              1           NaN
```

Comment: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: my names don't match my sample data exactly because it is protected data.  Translating the dict to the protected names though is {'area':{},'locale':{},'date':{},'# field':{},'i':{},'t':{},'o':{},'type':{}}

Comment: Can you provide full traceback of the error? It's hard to know what's causing the issue without looking at the actual data.

Comment: doing print(df.groupby('area')['date'].shift(-1)) works, so I am going to see about why it doesn't want to allow me to create the end date column

Comment: there was a bad print statement off my screen; I am testing the full output now

Comment: You can also try assign here and see if that works for you. `df = df.assign(end_date = df.groupby('area')['date'].shift(-1))`

Comment: It appears to; the load to the redshift with the dataframe is taking forever

Comment: Ahbi, I am checking back in I had to move to other projects for a time; it doesn't quite work.  It only works for the set abc, follow on sets shift wrong.  I posted a limited dataset.

Comment: @Shenanigator It's working just fine for me when tried on multiple datasets. If possible provide a dataset sample where it didn't work. You gotta provide more info to help mate! Maybe it could be the differences in your area column which resulting in the issue.

Comment: @Shenanigator Sorry for the late response. I was a little busy. It's working just fine for me when tried on multiple datasets. If possible provide a dataset sample where it didn't work. You gotta provide more info to help. Maybe it could be the differences in your area column which resulting in the issue. You can't expect us to understand your dataset from here mate.

Comment: just add an hij set after the def in a similar fashion.  It is possible that the differences in the actual data are contributing.  I am about to start working on it again today; get back soonest

Comment: I think there needs to be a reset index on the locale so that it shifts the dates inside each locale.  I am not having luck getting that working yet

Comment: Wrong key in the group by that was the issue.